# T-Statistics and/or P-Value

Tags: regression, fama-french

using models like fama-french 3 models, in some books like CFA curriculums, it was always mentioned to look at the T-statistics for the magic number '1.96' or 2 which tells us if it is statistically significant.

But i realized that sometimes even if T-statistics are very high say above 2 or 3, the p-value can still be very high as well ( above 0.05). Or it could be T-Statistics Low but p-value Low as well.

If that's the case would T-statistics still reliable or do investment practitioners also take note of p-value together with T-statistics?

These are some of the questions exercise i came across as below screenshot.

thanks a bunch - still a student but really interested in learning how you guys think

1st example...
[image]

2nd example...

[image]

Comment: T and P are directly linked. IMHO it cannot be that the value of one is changing without changing the other. Do you have a screenshot or sample code where this is different?

Comment: Hi Alex. thank you, i added some screenshots of some of the questions i came across when i am studying.. hopefully you can enlighten me on this

Comment: p-value is a probability, so it must lie between 0 and 1. 4.20 is simply impossible. Or is that 4.20%?

Comment: I suggest to read the details about this computation. Generally, a p value can simply be read from critical values of the t-distribution. It approaches the normal distribution for large degrees of freedom. That's why for anything above df 120 you can say that the 5% critical value is for a t-stat of 1.96. The values in your screenshots are nonsensical. For example, df must be as low as 2 so that a t-stat of 1.98 has a two tailed p value of 10%

Comment: Where are these exhibits from? Is this from the CFA curriculum? If so, I wouldn't be surprised if the numbers are just made up. E.g. you cannot get the t-stat from the coefficients and the standard error in the does one but it works in the second one (it's just coef/SE). They probably didn't bother looking up correct values from t-tables.

Comment: Thanks all. I i think i agree that the questions i got were all made up numbers by the curriculum, which confuses me and made my doubt my thinking.